# SOAP returning XML in one level object

Tags: php, soap

I'm making a soap call that should return as follows:

```
<RESPONSE>
    <SUCCESS>true</SUCCESS>
    <ERRORMESSAGE> </ERRORMESSAGE>
    <TIMESTAMP>26/06/2018 14:50:47</TIMESTAMP>
    <AUDITID>34817024</AUDITID>
</RESPONSE>
```

However it's actually returning the results as follows

```
stdClass Object
(
[DVLALookupVRMResult] => stdClass Object
    (
        [any] => true26/06/2018 14:50:4734817024
    )

)
```

The code I'm using to do the lookup is as follows:

```
$client = new SoapClient($url);

$data=[
    'SubscriberID'=>'****',
    'Password'=>'****'
];

try{
    $output = $client->CorrectField($data);

}

catch(soapFault $e)
{
    print "<pre>";
    print_r($e);
    print "</pre>";
}

print "<pre>";
print_r($output);
print "</pre>";
```

Comment: You can try this http://php.net/soapclient.getlastresponse

Comment: Try view source, browser may not be displaying xml tags in output.

Comment: @Dharmang view source shows tags! `
stdClass Object
(
    [lookup] => stdClass Object
        (
            [any] => <RESPONSE xmlns=""><SUCCESS>true</SUCCESS>`

Comment: @Dharmang how would I go about formatting it to display xml tags in the output if they're there in the source?

Comment: The response you are getting is string so you need to use SimpleXML to convert it into object.